# Android Studio persistently running after installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I had installed android studio but after installing it is showing

```
Android studio is currently running please exit the application and press ok to continue.
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue please help.

Thank you

Comment: Force close it in your task manager/system monitor?

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when the packages are being installed in the background, and we gave an instruction to open it, You can either go to the path where you stored the androidSDK and check for its size it would be around 11gb, to verify its properly installed,
Or my advice will be just re-install with a stable internet connection. It will definitely work, give him some time to set in your laptop since its a heavy software
Feel free to contact for any other query.

Hope it Helps !!